# Rails image_tag full path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I have images in my assets folder and path to it

```
"app/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg"
```

so i want to use it like

`Dir.glob("app/assets/images/sets/*.jpg")` it return me `"app/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg"`

`image_tag("app/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg")`   but it gives me empty image

Is it possible if so how to fix it?

Comment: `image_tag("/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg")` will do your thing!

Comment: ok, them how i can get this path from `Dir.glob` @MuhammadYawarAli

Comment: just trim app from the image url `"app/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg".gsub("app", "")`.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli `image_tag("/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg")` don't work for me

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I have found is to do this: The [asset_url](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_url) tag will put the full url of the asset (in this case an image called: "app-store.png") and then it will be passed to the image_tag normally.

```
<%= image_tag "#{ asset_url "app-store.png"}" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 :

```
<%= image_tag(image_url('sets/img_2168.jpg')) %>
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:

```
<%= image_tag("sets/" + File.basename(Dir.glob("app/assets/images/sets/*").first))%>
```

If you just provide `"sets/img_2168.jpg"` to `image_tag`, it should work.

You don't need to provide the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
image_tag(File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s + '/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg'}").url)
  OR
<img src="/assets/images/sets/img_2168.jpg"></img>
```

Ideally you should pass image object from the controller and in image_tag just get its url like :

```
image_tag(@image_obj.url)
```